# Authenticating static content in Tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat, servlet-3.0

I want to authenticate static content in tomcat using form authentication.
Currently I have packaged static content inside WAR ,using security constraint & login-config was able to achieve. Since its pure static content, I wanted to know if I can avoid packaging as WAR. Leave the static content as folder & write separate authentication jar.
I could not find any information in Servlet 3.0 .
Any pointers please?

Comment: If you don't mind using a third party framework, I think you could achieve this with [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/).

Comment: You should take a look at this tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjiie.html

Comment: I think hot deployment can solve the issue